# Form alter not working

Tags: 7, forms, rating

I used custom module to alter comment form.in that module i write below code to remove required option for fivestar rating field. but it is not working.

```
$form['field_rating_comment']['und']['0']['value']['#required'] = FALSE;
$form['field_rating_comment']['#required'] = FALSE;
```

both are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an entity then you can remove the required property from manage fields option in comment.

```
$form['field_rating_comment']['und']['0']['rating']['#required'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: i want to remove required for only comment reply form.but in the main comment form should need require.

Comment: I think instead of value you can try rating

Comment: please mark this as acceptable if it solves your problem